# How to make sense of tensorflow tensorboard Histograms?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, deep-learning, caffe

I would like to know how to make sense of the tensor flow graphs/Histograms generated.
The code for this can be found [here.](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py)
This graph is easy to understand Accuracy and loss are straight forward to understand.

```
Accuracy- Accuracy of current state of network for given train data.
Higher is better

Accuracy/Validation -  Accuracy of current state of network for given Validation data which is 
not seen by network before. Higher is better

Loss- Loss of network on train data. Lower is better.
Loss/Valadation - Loss of network on test data. Lower is better.
If loss increases it's a sign of over-fitting.
Conv2d/L2-Loss - Loss of particular layer wrt train data.
```

[image]

Basically what the graph signifies and how i could use it to understand my network and if possible what changes i can make to improve it.

## How Do I interpret the histograms?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**tf.summary.histogram** takes an arbitrarily sized and shaped Tensor, and compresses it into a histogram data structure consisting of many bins with widths and counts. For example, let's say we want to organize the numbers [0.5, 1.1, 1.3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.99] into bins. We could make three bins: a bin containing everything from 0 to 1 (it would contain one element, 0.5), a bin containing everything from 1-2 (it would contain two elements, 1.1 and 1.3), * a bin containing everything from 2-3 (it would contain three elements: 2.2, 2.9 and 2.99).

Please follow below links for more details:

[sunside answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms)

[Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tensorboard_histograms)